# What is the order of the quantifiers in the definition of big-O?

Tags: logic, asymptotics

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions. I am pretty sure that the definition of big-O has its definition conform to the following logical structure

$$\exists \, k \, \exists C \, \forall \,x\, :\, x > k \implies|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$$

since it also conforms to proper usage when attempting to prove by contradiction that $f$ is not big-O of $g$, but I would like confirmation.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want a quantifier for $x$ somewhere instead of letting it be a free variable of your definition ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I agree with you. Honestly, I wrote the logical structure down with $x$ having the universal quantifier, but I accidentally dropped it when I typed it. I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Under the assumption that you surely want to make that we are talking about what it means that $f$ is $O(g)$ as $x \to \infty$ (and not some other point, or still something else).

More generally, $f$ is $O(g)$ on $S$ means that there exists some $C$ such that $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$ for all $x \in S$ (equivalently $x \in S $ implies $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$).

And, $f$ is $O(g)$ as $x \to p$ means that there exists some open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a  $C$ (that may depend on $U$) such that $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$ for all $x \in U$ (equivalently $x \in U $ implies $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$).

The sets $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x  >k\}$ are a basis of the open neighborhoods of $+\infty$. This second statement is thus equivalently to what you said.

In particular, it is more coherent to  choose the neighborhood first and then the constant. But in the particular case you could also invert the order of the existential quantifiers and it would not yield  a different definition in this case.

Comment: ... wait, you agree with the OP that it is correct to have the variable $x$ appear in the formula without $\forall x$ or $\exists x$ anywhere?

Comment: Mainly I focused my answer on the main question  whether the order of the two existential statements is as given or the other way round. But yes,  as the formula in OP contains an implication, and I parse it as: there exists $k$, there exits $C$ such that the implication is true.

Comment: I'm not talking about the implication -- I'm talking about the fact that the variable $x$ is free in the formula, whereas it should have been quantified. (And _where_ the variable is quantified is of critical importance here).

Comment: I understand the formula as a transcription of: "There exists a $k$ and there exists a $C$ such that the following is true:  If $x>k$, then $|f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$." This sentence seems like a correct definition to me. It is not exactly clear to me where we deviate.

Comment: I think it should be "There exists a $k$ and there exists a C such that **for every $x$** it holds that if $x>k$ then $|f(x)\le C|g(x)|$". It's a mystery to me why you think it would make sense to leave $x$ free as a parameter in the definition of the property, rather than have it quantified. The only free variables in the definition should be $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Because  "(If) $x>k$, then..." for an unspecified/unquantified $x$ is commonly understood in the intended .way, and I do not think the point of the question was writing formulas formally correct (there'd be various other issues then too) but, as said, to clarify in which order the two existential quantifier are to be used. That said, if I had paid attention to this detail I might have written a half-sentence about it.